# String substitution operators with lists in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

I would like to be able to create a string using printf like functionality, with the variables drawn from a list and inserted into a template string.

i.e.

```
let templateStr = "First comes %s, then comes %s, after which comes %s"
let vars = ["one","two", "three"]
```

and some function returns:

```
function returns >>> First comes one, then comes two, after which comes three
```

i.e. in Python I could do something like:

```
>>> templateStr = "First comes %s, then comes %s, after which comes %s"
>>> vars = ["one","two", "three"]
>>> outputStr = tempStr % tuple(vars)
>>> print outputStr
First comes one, then comes two, after which comes three
```

**My Attempt**

```
mergeList :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mergeList [] ys = ys
mergeList (x:xs) ys = x:mergeList ys xs

-- not actually needed * use: Prelude.concat
listConcat :: [[a]] -> [a]
listConcat [] = []
listConcat (x:xs) = x ++ listConcat xs

-- via @dfeuer list concat is not need because of Prelude.concat
printf' :: String -> [String] -> String
printf' s v = concat $ mergeList (splitOn "%s" s) v
```

**Attempt via @Reid Barton**

```
printf' :: String -> [String] -> String
printf' ('%':'s':rest) (v:vs) = v ++ printf' rest vs
printf' (c:rest)        vs    = c :  printf' rest vs
printf' []              _     = []
```

both attempts give

```
>>> let templateStr = "First comes %s, then comes %s, after which comes %s"
>>> let vars = ["one","two", "three"]
>>> printf' templateStr vars
"First comes one, then comes two, after which comes three"
```

Comment: You can write this particular function yourself rather easily. But you will find things start to get trickier if you want to support other `printf`-style format specifiers. There actually is a Haskell version of `printf`, but it's a bit ... weird.

Comment: @dfeuer any help with how to write the function? I am new to Haskell... thanks. I only need this specific functionality with strings. Maybe something like `splitOn "%s"`   then `zip`  and `concat` the two lists??? Would that be an efficient way to do it? (assuming that I can even do that)

Comment: I think it's definitely a good idea to think about the utilities in `Data.List.Split`! You're probably getting close. Why don't you try out your idea and see where it leads? If you get properly stuck, we'll be happy to help.

Comment: The term to google is "string interpolation".

Comment: @dfeuer would please critique my attempt and perhaps show me how I can improve it. Thanks!

Comment: Your attempt seems to be a perfectly acceptable implementation... but there is already a `concat` function.

Comment: See [Text.Printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Text-Printf.html) for a reference

Answer (score 3):

The outline of another, more direct approach:

```
printf' ('%':'s':rest) (v:vs) = ...
printf' (c:rest)       vs     = ...
... -- handle the remaining cases too
```

Comment: would you please look at my attempt at your approach, and perhaps complete your outline so that I can tick it as the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Great start! `mergeList` is very clean.

```
mergeList :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mergeList [] ys = ys
mergeList (x:xs) ys = x:mergeList ys xs



listConcat :: [String] -> String
listConcat [] = []
listConcat (x:xs)
  | null xs   = x
  | otherwise = x ++ listConcat xs
```

You can do better than this for `listConcat`. In particular, you currently use two base cases for the recursion, but you only need one. Furthermore, you can change the type signature to `listConcat :: [[a]] -> [a]` to make it more general. Once you've cleaned up your version: There's a function like that in the standard library. Can you find it?

Comment: I have amended by listConcat above. Then I realised I could have done `listConcat' s = foldr (++) "" s` ?? and then after your post I found the actual `Prelude.concat`, which oddly enough was the first thing I thought of but for some reason it didn't work when I first tried it (hence be stumbling through trying to make my own). So I guess `concat $ mergeList (splitOn "%s" s) v`. Is that a solid solution? I like your Socratic method btw!!!

Comment: @matthias, your revised function won't work on empty lists. The `foldr` one is fine, but you can generalize it to arbitrary lists.

Comment: @dfeur I have changed my base case to `listConcat [] = []`. I am not sure what you mean regarding the `foldr`